# Consumir WebService SOAP con Genexus Ev2 o Ev3 de DGI para factura electrónica

Tags: webservice, genexus, soap

Alguien sabe cómo consumir un WebService SOAP que usa WS-Security con Genexus ?

El WebService en cuestión es de la DGI, para factura electrónica, y la dirección es la siguiente: https://efactura.dgi.gub.uy:6460/ePrueba/ws_consultasPrueba?wsdl

Ya he buscado información por todo lados pero no he encontrado nada que me sirva. El WSDL lo puedo importar perfectamente con el *WSDL Inspector* de Genexus, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar.

El programa compila, pero cuando trato de ejecutarlo, me tira la siguiente excepción:

```
Grave: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [com.wsdgiev3.webpanel1] en el contexto con ruta [/WSDGIEV3JavaEnvironment] lanzó la excepción [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel$DynAjaxEvent.doInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel$DynAjaxEvent.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webAjaxEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webExecuteEx(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.wsdgiev3.webpanel1.doExecute(webpanel1.java:23)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood(-1)
    at com.wsdgiev3.SdtWS_eFactura_Consultas.efacconsultarestadocfe(SdtWS_eFactura_Consultas.java:208)
    at com.wsdgiev3.pruebas_ws_dgi.privateExecute(pruebas_ws_dgi.java:50)
    at com.wsdgiev3.pruebas_ws_dgi.execute_int(pruebas_ws_dgi.java:40)
    at com.wsdgiev3.pruebas_ws_dgi.execute(pruebas_ws_dgi.java:32)
    at com.wsdgiev3.webpanel1_impl.e11072(webpanel1_impl.java:512)
    ... 38 more
] con causa raíz
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel$DynAjaxEvent.doInvoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel$DynAjaxEvent.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webAjaxEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.webExecuteEx(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebPanel.doExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.wsdgiev3.webpanel1.doExecute(webpanel1.java:23)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callDoExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: MustUnderstand headers:[{http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd}Security] are not understood(-1)
    at com.wsdgiev3.SdtWS_eFactura_Consultas.efacconsultarestadocfe(SdtWS_eFactura_Consultas.java:208)
    at com.wsdgiev3.pruebas_ws_dgi.privateExecute(pruebas_ws_dgi.java:50)
    at com.wsdgiev3.pruebas_ws_dgi.execute_int(pruebas_ws_dgi.java:40)
    at com.wsdgiev3.pruebas_ws_dgi.execute(pruebas_ws_dgi.java:32)
    at com.wsdgiev3.webpanel1_impl.e11072(webpanel1_impl.java:512)
    ... 38 more

    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.callExecute(Unknown Source)
    at com.genexus.webpanels.GXWebObjectStub.doPost(Unknown Source)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at com.genexus.filters.ExpiresFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Hola!. _no logro hacerlo funcionar_ no es una excelente descripción de lo que está ocurriendo. ¿hay algún mensaje de error al ejecutar una llamada? ¿el programa no compila? ¿cuál es el mensaje de error?. Te invito a leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask y https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

Te sugiero que veas el documento [WS-Security DGI (Efactura) WebServices](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?18986) del Wiki de GeneXus.

Allí explica los pasos a seguir tanto para Java como para .Net.

Comment: Ese documento ya lo utilicé para los servicios principales de DGI, que funciona, con muchos problemas, pero funciona. El que preciso ahora es el de consultas, que es otro.